# My commands are not working in 1.12

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have made a small command creation in 1.11.2 that makes giant zombies from normal zombies. Basically you throw a red mushroom at a normal zombie and it grows in to a giant zombie. Now this worked fine as logn as i was in 1.11 and 1.11.2 but in 1.12 it's broken and i don't know how to fix it. I know that they have made again some changes to the command blocks but i don't know what they did.

Here are the commands:

1.Repeating-Unconditional-Always active

```
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=Item] add red_mushroom {Item:{id:minecraft:red_mushroom}}
```

2.Chain-Unconditional-Always active

```
/execute @e[tag=red_mushroom] ~ ~ ~ /tp @e[type=zombie,c=1,r=1] ~ ~-500 ~
```

3.Chain-Conditional-Always active

```
/execute @e[tag=red_mushroom] ~ ~ ~ /summon Giant ~ ~ ~ {CanPickUpLoot:true}
```

4.Chain-Conditional-Always active

```
/execute @e[tag=red_mushroom] ~ ~ ~ execute @e[type=giant,c=1,r=1] ~ ~ ~ kill @e[tag=red_mushroom,r=1,c=1]
```

I had some others command creations in my test world and many similar to this has also broken.

Comment: Keys and Strings containing special characters are now required to be encased in quotes. `id:minecraft:red_mushroom` -> `id:"minecraft:red_mushroom"`

Comment: thanks it worked now i was trying to fix this sinse 1.12 pre 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just to complete this one:

As of 1.12 it is required to encase all Strings (values) and keys in quotes which contain characters other than:

- a-z (upper and lowercase)
- 0-9
- . _ + -

This means your `:` is out of bounds and the value String need to be encased:
`id:minecraft:red_mushroom` has to be formatted as `id:"minecraft:red_mushroom"` for the command to work.

Other examples:

- `key name: someValue` does not work (space in key); `"key name":someValue`does work
- `keyName: some Value` (space in value String); needs to be `keyName: "some Value"`
- `keyName: $someValue` does not work (`$` in value String); needs to be `keyName: "$someValue"`
- `keyName: someValue` does work