# How to testfor a custom item in player off hand 1.12 version

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do you `testfor` a player holding a stick named `Rainbow Stick` and have the lore `The best stick!` in version 1.12?

Comment: The command should be something like `/testfor @p {Inventory:[{Slot:-106b,id:"minecraft:stick", tag:{display:{Name:"Rainbow Stick", Lore:"The best stick!"}}}]}` ...remember to encase names and values with spaces or : in them in `" "` (required as of 1.12)

Answer (score 2):

Didn't have access to Minecraft when I posted the comment, so just to finalize this question again as answer...

The part to access the offhand slot is `Slot:-106b` so the command is as follows:

`/testfor @p {Inventory:[{Slot:-106b,id:"minecraft:stick", tag:{display:{Name:"Rainbow Stick", Lore:"The best stick!"}}}]}`

As of 1.12 it is required to encase Strings with `" "` if they contain non-whitelisted characters (including `:` and spaces). [This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/310745/my-commands-are-not-working-in-1-12/310807#310807) explains it.